# Picking bundle IDs for eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, osgi

Consider an open source project hosted at github that publishes Eclipse plugins.

Options:

1. Buy a domain name and use it.
2. com.github.something
3. make something up and figure that it's not too likely that anyone else
   will pick exactly the same thing.

Anyone have practical experience or guidance to share?

Answer (score 2):

`com.github.something`.

I've seen projects on SourceForge use `net.sf.*` for package names, so there's precedent. I use `li.earth.urchin.twic.*`, based on my email address, even though that domain has nothing much to do with any of the code i write.

I suspect it doesn't really matter. For what it's worth, i find it really annoying when a package name doesn't use a reversed domain name - when it's `foobar.util` rather than `org.foobar.util`. It makes me think the packagers were lazy or arrogant. I have absolutely no objective reason to think that, of course!

Answer (score 1):

See [How should I name packages if I don't have a domain associated with me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166051/how-should-i-name-packages-if-i-dont-have-a-domain-associated-with-me) for more possible answers.

In general, I second Tom Anderson - it doesn't really matter. You might use the com.github name, to represent, where to look for the project (but if for some reason the project is migrated, this might become impractical).

Or if you don't want to rely on the existing address, you could either buy a domain or use some personal id - just as feels right.