# Should I use my open-source hosting platform's domain name for my packages?

Tags: java, package

I'm currently in the process of moving my project from Google Code to Github. When I initially created my project I used com.googlecode.* for my package names. Now I'm moving to Github so switching my packages to com.github.* seems appropriate.

However, others have pointed out to me that having to change my packages each time I move hosting platforms (which could change a lot given all the recent hosting fads) could be a problem. They suggest I should use my own domain name, but I'm sceptical about this approach: domain names can expire and the overheads for maintaining a domain name, although not arduous, aren't minimal either.

What are the pros and cons to following approaches:

1. Keeping the packages as-is (com.googlecode.*) even though it's misleading?
2. Move to com.github.* as planned even though I might to switch?
3. Pay to register my own domain name for stability, despite the additional overhead?
4. Borrow a friends domain name?

Even though the domain name package naming convention is just a convention, I know the central Maven repository won't let you upload under domain name packages unless you can demonstrate you've registered the DNS entry, so it is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Donal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166051/how-should-i-name-packages-if-i-dont-have-a-domain-associated-with-me/166326#166326) from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166051/448201) -- use a dynamic DNS service that can point to all sorts of places.

He suggests [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) but I prefer the available domains from [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html).

Changing the packages every time you move hosting platforms is very annoying.

Alternatively, buy a vanity domain for your own personal use (e.g. blogging) and use that instead. When you look at options, bear in mind that .uk domains are a lot cheaper than .com/.org (£3-4 / year as opposed to £10 / year).

Comment: Thanks Adam, I already use No-IP so I might well do as you say. Which No-IP package do I need? No-IP Plus?

Comment: I think you can go for the free package -- otherwise you might as well buy a real domain :-)

Answer (score 5):

com.domain is commonly used to determine author's domain. So using your own corporate's domain name is the most appropriate (If don't have one just buy one they are pretty cheap). If don't or can't buy one then just use your product's name. I don't see how use com.googlecode or com.github could be useful or at least have sense.

Just my two cents.

Comment: *One I say can't buy one, don't say it by money but because the one you want is already registered. (Happens all the time)

Comment: Well com.googlecode or com.github are useful because that's where I host my code. It's the simplest option because I don't have to register a domain myself. That's why it makes sense. Could you expand on your reasoning? I also note that using my product name as root package folder is not appropriate, because I don't think that's allowed on Maven central. Finally, I did explain that I would like to avoid if possible registering my own domain with the money and time to administer it involved unless I have to.

Comment: google code and github host millions of projects. If your project is named X then the probability of another project called X its pretty big.
Those names exists precisely to unique identify projects. So, if to projects are named com.google.X and you need to use them (both) you can't. If it's only your project it doesn't mind (you'll think) but scale that to the open source world and you'll see how commonly are two projects sharing name but different packages.

Comment: While google code does host millions of projects, each of those project names must be unique, so as long as you use com.googlecode.{project_name} you are ok. Same for github as long as you use com.github.{user_id}.{project_name} so your argument doesn't follow in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to propose

5) Just use (org|net|com).yourproject, and don't buy the domain

6) Just use something you feel comfortable with, like your last name or the plain project title

It depends a bit on how popular you expect your project to become, but even if it becomes popular this is no problem. Junit and Hamcrest are famous examples.
Otherwise, I would go with 4). Since a package name always implies ownership, I would not use names of unrelated companies.

But most importantly: don't worry too much and do what you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Adrian. The only thing I would say is that I think getting your project onto Maven central means you do have to prove you have the domain name registered, so I would probably need to buy the domain if I didn't use the hosting project domain name.